# error while installing spree-commerece gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree, sprockets

I am trying to install `gem 'spree', '3.0.5' in my rails app.

Here's what I have in my `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', github: 'rails/sass-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported  runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.  Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:      https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a     debugger console
gem 'byebug'

# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'
end

gem 'spree', '3.0.5'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Here's what I am getting when I hit `bundle install`

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
>     In Gemfile:
>       sass-rails was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
>         sprockets (>= 4.0)
>
> Could not find gem 'sprockets (>= 4.0)', which is required by gem
>   'sass-rails', in any of the sources.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Solidus, it's a fork of Spree, Spree isn't actively maintained anymore, Solidus is.

https://solidus.io/

Github: https://github.com/solidusio/solidus

If you run into any more problems, please reply and I'll help you through it.

EDIT:

Seems spree is continuing development with a new development team for 2016.

To answer your question, try the stable 3.x version

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/6964

Comment: I am not sure If I could think of it at the moment. I'd love to go with Spree

Comment: Why is that, Solidus is almost exactly the same code, but with improvements and it is actively maintained.

Comment: I see that the last commit on the repo was just couple of hours back

Comment: You are right, seems they've updated the README 6 days ago announcing a new development roadmap for 2016.

Comment: Is 3.0.5 working for you now ? If it doesn't I'd try the stable 3.x version `spree install my_store --branch "3-0-stable"` and upgrade later on. The edge versions are not guaranteed to be bug-free.